# SPOTFIRE how do I shape by column in the map chart with a custom expression

Tags: shapes, spotfire

I have a spotfire question. I am attempting to create **Shapes by Column Values** in a **Map Chart**.

I would like to create these **Shapes** by a **Custom Expression**. The custom expression is below, I have simplified it so it is easier to read.

All I am saying is:

if((Current months oil rate - 12MonthAgo Oilrate)/12MonthAgo Oilrate)>0,"UP","Down")

When I run this calculation though it only gives me one value, (there are both positives and negatives so it should give two).

I am not sure what I have done wrong? Any help is appreciated.

```
 <If(((((Sum(If(CurrentMonth),[OILRATECD],null))
    - 
Sum(If(12MonthsAgo),[OILRATECD],null)))))
    /
Sum(If(12MonthsAgo),[OILRATECD],null)))>0,"UP","DOWN")>
```

ORIGINAL EQUATION:

```
 <If(((((Sum(If((Month([DATE])=Month(DateAdd("mm",-2,DateTimeNow()))) and (Year([DATE])=Year(DateAdd("mm",-2,DateTimeNow()))),[OILRATECD],null))
    - 
Sum(If((Month([DATE])=Month(DateAdd("mm",-${MonthInterval}-2,DateTimeNow()))) and (Year([DATE])=Year(DateAdd("mm",-${MonthInterval}-2,DateTimeNow()))),[OILRATECD],null)))))
    /
Sum(If((Month([DATE])=Month(DateAdd("mm",-${MonthInterval}-2,DateTimeNow()))) and (Year([DATE])=Year(DateAdd("mm",-${MonthInterval}-2,DateTimeNow()))),[OILRATECD],null)))>0,"UP","DOWN")>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a lot of unnecessary parentheses but that shouldn't hurt anything.

```
If(
    (
        ( --this open parentheses is unneeded
            ( --this open parentheses is unneeded
                (
                    Sum(If((Month([DATE])=Month(DateAdd("mm",-2,DateTimeNow()))) and (Year([DATE])=Year(DateAdd("mm",-2,DateTimeNow()))),[OILRATECD],null))
                    - 
                    Sum(If((Month([DATE])=Month(DateAdd("mm",-${MonthInterval}-2,DateTimeNow()))) and (Year([DATE])=Year(DateAdd("mm",-${MonthInterval}-2,DateTimeNow()))),[OILRATECD],null))
                )
            ) --this closed parentheses is unneeded
        ) --this closed parentheses is unneeded
        /
        Sum(If((Month([DATE])=Month(DateAdd("mm",-${MonthInterval}-2,DateTimeNow()))) and (Year([DATE])=Year(DateAdd("mm",-${MonthInterval}-2,DateTimeNow()))),[OILRATECD],null))
    )
    >0,"UP","DOWN")
```

The reason you are not getting `UP` and `DOWN` returned is because the condition isn't met. **We need a sample data set with expected output to verify this**.

However, here's a reason why you could be getting unexpected results, regarding `NULL` in your `SUM(IF(...,[OILRATECD],NULL))` expression.

**TL;DR**

> If your condtion in your `IF()` statement isn't ever evaluated to true
>   then `NULL` is returned to `SUM()`, and `SUM(NULL,NULL,NULL) = NULL`
>   and `NULL` is not `>` nor is it `<` 0, thus your outer `IF()`
>   statement would return `NULL` instead of "UP" or "DOWN"

**LONG VERSION**

1. Spotfire ignored `NULL` when evaluating `SUM()` **which is what you want**. For example, `Sum(4,3,NULL) = 7` and this is the behavior we want. **However...**
2. Spotfire doesn't ignore `NULL` for addition, subtraction, division, and other comparison operators like `>`. So, `4 - NULL = NULL` and `NULL / 18 = NULL` and so on. This means if either of your two `SUM()` methods return `NULL` then your entire expression will be `NULL` **because...**
3. `NULL` isn't `>` nor is it `<` and certainly not `=` 0. `NULL` is the absence of a value, and thus can't be compared or equated to anything. For example, `If(NULL > 1,"YES","NO")` doesn't return YES or NO... it returns `NULL`, the lack of a value. Also, `If(NULL=NULL,"YES","NO")` will also return `NULL`

**HOW TO GET AROUND THIS**

Use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` in a `IF()` statement to set it to a default value, or use 0 in place of `NULL` in your current expression.

`Sum(If((Month([DATE])=Month(DateAdd("mm",-2,DateTimeNow()))) and (Year([DATE])=Year(DateAdd("mm",-2,DateTimeNow()))),[OILRATECD],0))`

**BIG SIDE NOTE**

You said your equation's pseudo code is:

```
If((Current months oil rate - 12MonthAgo Oilrate)/12MonthAgo Oilrate)>0,"UP","Down")
```

This doesn't seem to be what you are evaluating. Instead, I read:

```
x = (-var) + (-2) thus var < -2 (i.e. -3....-6...-55)
if((sum([2 months ago oil rate]) - sum([x months ago oil rate])) > 0, "UP","DOWN")
```

So you aren't ever looking at the current month's oil rate, but instead are looking at current - 2. Also, you are looking at the `SUM()` over that entire month... this may be what you want by you *may* be actually looking for `Max()` or `Min()`

**OVER FUNCTION**

You can handle this a lot easier most likely with a few calculated columns to keep your data / expressions clean and legible

1. `DatePart("yy",[Date]) as [Year]`
2. `DatePart("mm",[Date]) as [Month]`
3. `Max([OILRATECD]) OVER (Intersect([Year],[Month])) as [YearMonthRate]` or use `SUM()` if that's what you really want.
4. Check to see the difference with `Rank()`

Comment: Hey Thanks for all that! I changed the nulls to 0 to test but It still did not work. I will look into it and see if I made a mistake somewhere. (PS on your side note, yes I know, I didnt want to explain that I must do things lagging two months previous because I felt it would confuse my issue) im not sure the calc columns will work, we want to be able to change the time frame with property controls. But maybe they will. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @brandog Can you provide some sample data that's throwing the error? Then we can recreate it into a MCVE and figure out your issue and solve the problem.

Comment: sorry for the very late reply. I cant provide any sample data, but I realized it would not work anyway. Due to the fact I switch between monthly intervals the data is always changing, sometimes they will all be positive, next time all negative, then both. Spotfire will not let you set a shape so even if it worked the shape would be randomized each time you selected a new month interval. Thanks though.